# meaning of "warbled out these metres meet"

Tags: meaning

It is from a poem written by William Blake:

> "Love seeketh not itself to please,
> Nor for itself hath any care,
> But for another gives its ease,
> And builds a Heaven in Hell's despair."
>
> So sung a little Clod of Clay
> Trodden with the cattle's feet,
> But a Pebble of the brook
> **Warbled out these metres meet:**
>
> "Love seeketh only self to please,
> To bind another to its delight,
> Joys in another's loss of ease,
> And builds a Hell in Heaven's despite."

Warble's definition on [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/warble): (of a person) sing in a trilling or quavering voice.

But I have no idea the meaning of the sentence. Could anyone help?

---

---

Update:

[**meet**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meet): [adjective] precisely adapted to a particular situation, need, or circumstance : very proper

OR [archaic] suitable or proper.

[**meter**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meter): systematically arranged and measured rhythm in verse:

1. rhythm that continuously repeats a single basic pattern
2. rhythm characterized by regular recurrence of a systematic arrangement of basic patterns in larger figures

Comment: Have you also looked up the less common meanings of "metre" and "meet", in particular those that are *meet* to the context of quoting poetry?

Comment: I found out the less common meanings of "metre" and "meet". It helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep in mind the biblical idea that God created man from dust. So "a clod of clay" is one person. And "a pebble" is another person. So these are two people making claims about love. Also, a pebble "of the brook" is in sharp contrast to the clay. The pebble will be washed by the brook and so clean, maybe even sparkly.

The [metre](https://www.britannica.com/art/metre-music) of a song is the rhythm or beat. For example, the number of beats to a bar.

Something is "meet" if it meets the purpose. That is, it does what it was intended.

So **"the pebble sang a song that clearly expressed an idea"**. In this case, the idea opposite to what the clod of clay said.

Salute to you trying to learn English from poetry by William Blake. You set yourself a high bar. It is poetry, and it is from far enough in the past that English usage has changed somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
By the way, is there a way to rephrase "warble out ..."? Could I say "warble out where these meters meet" or "warble out of the meters"?

Comment: No. In this case "meet" is not referring to two things coming together. It is indicating fitness for purpose. The words are meet for the purpose. That's part of the usage I mentioned. People rarely use meet that way these days. You could say "warbleld" (or sang) "these fine words."

Comment: So "meet" here is an adjective that means: "precisely adapted to a particular situation, need, or circumstance : very proper". Right?

Comment: @H.Li: Despite BillOnne's encouraging words above, I certainly wouldn't encourage you to think of Blake's work as a useful resource for learning English! Quite apart from the fact that poetry in general isn't usually suitable for this purpose, Blake was writing *a long time ago.* Most "ordinary" Anglophones today would have trouble fully understanding his output! Even I struggle with some of it, and I was so fascinated by Blake's work when I was a teenager that I bought "the complete works" at a cost of more than I earned in a week!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks for your input. I randomly came across this poem and felt just like it. To me, it's fun to search for its meaning. I guess I have an old soul. lol

Comment: @H.Li: I absolutely agree that "just liking it" is an *excellent* reason for reading poetry (and other "stylised" literary content). But it's a bit beyond the scope of ELL here.